# Sum of two table columns based on a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 tables (adapted to this question):

**Accounts Table**

```
Money In | Money Out | Person
0          100         Frank
0          20          Frank
0          15          Tom
10         0           Frank
```

**Items Table**

```
Item Purchased | Cost | Person
Apple            15     Frank
Pear             10     Tom
Banana           30     Frank
```

What I would like is a table which outputs the amount of money each person owes. For the above example, the output I would like is:

```
Person | Money Owed
Frank    65
Tom      5
```

The basic formula is as follows:

```
Money Owed = [Money Out] - [Money In] - [Cost]
```

I am trying to avoid writing an actual program to do this as Excel is easier to share with others.

I am having trouble thinking of a formula to put into the `Money Owed` cell for compute this per person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `SUMIF` to calculate each part of the formula. Assuming that each table is in its own sheet, you could do something like this:

```
=SUMIF(Accounts!C:C, A2, Accounts!B:B) - SUMIF(Accounts!C:C, A2, Accounts!A:A) - SUMIF(Items!C:C, A2, Items!B:B)
```

Where A2 contains `Frank`.

`SUMIF` is as follows:

```
SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])
```

So, it will sum the `[sum_range]` for all rows (in this case) within `range` meeting the `criteria`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize you could add the column name.

Comment: @rhughes Oh, those aren't the column names. I assumed they were in different sheets, like one sheet named `Accounts` and another named `Items`. If you have a table as in, an excel formatted table, then there's a specific syntax for those, though it's not required to always use that particular syntax.

Comment: I found that out, thanks. I meant `B` etc... I thought you had to use the table syntax (which I had wrong it seems anyways :))

Comment: @rhughes You could use the table syntax I guess, but that's usually a little more complicated ^^; I could add one such formula in my answer should you want to.

Comment: Your a busy guy - I'm happy with what you have given me already, thanks! :)

Comment: @rhughes Okay then, should you need the table version, leave me a comment here :)